# Calling Azure Function from Azure Data Factory Gives 404 Error

Tags: azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Function named "SendTemplateEmail" that has an HTTP Trigger.

[image]

I'd like to call this from an Azure Data Factory Pipeline.

I've created a new linked service and configured as follows:

[image]

I've configures the Azure Function task within the ADF Pipeline as follows:

[image]

When I run the pipeline, I get the following error:

[image]

**Works if using Web Task**

If I make the call from the pipeline using a web task configured as follows then the call to the Azure function is successful:

[image]

Is there any way to figure out the URL the pipeline is trying to reach?

Answer (score 0):

This error is expected when there is no Function App found with the requested URL. Before triggering the Azure Function pipeline, make sure your Azure Function App is in **Running** state.

Start the **Function App** by clicking on Start Symbol on overview page.

[image]

Comment: But the function app must be running otherwise the call from the data factory's web task would also fail?

Comment: Yes, bcoz a stopped azure function results in no execution of data factory activity

Comment: Therefore your answer must be incorrect, because as mentioned in my initial post, the data factory web task is successful when calling the same Azure Function

Comment: Have you tried to start the azure function before triggering ADF pipeline?

Comment: It is already started